PuppeteerSharp v.17.0.0 how to use?
I am using PuppeteerSharp verson 10.1.4 and it is working super fine.
I have seen that there is a version 17.0.0 now and I tried to update to this version, but then nothing in my C# code worked any more. And I had to return to use the version 10.1.4.
I have looked around and not been able to find any description on how to use PuppeteerSharp in the newer version.
I am using only XPaths to locate things. So I using a lot of this "page.XPathAsync(xpath);", but I cannot figure out how this is working in the newer version.
Anybody can help whit link to some place there there is a description/tuturial on how to make the never version work?
Follow up:
This is the code I using under PupperteerSharp 10.1.4, and it working OK:
I like to use specially XPATH as the selector:
using PuppeteerSharp;
using System;

namespace Test_PupetteerSharp;


public class Scraper
{
    public async Task Run()
    {
        ViewPortOptions vpo = new ViewPortOptions();
        vpo.Width = 1920;
        vpo.Height = 1280;

        BrowserFetcherOptions bfo = new BrowserFetcherOptions()
        {
            Path = System.IO.Path.GetTempPath()
        };

        BrowserFetcher browserFetcher = new BrowserFetcher(bfo);

        await browserFetcher.DownloadAsync(BrowserFetcher.DefaultChromiumRevision);

        var lo = new LaunchOptions()
        {
            Headless = false,
            DefaultViewport = vpo,
            ExecutablePath = browserFetcher.RevisionInfo(BrowserFetcher.DefaultChromiumRevision.ToString()).ExecutablePath
        };

        try
        {
            using (IBrowser browser = await Puppeteer.LaunchAsync(lo))
            {
                using (IPage page = await browser.NewPageAsync())
                {
                    await page.Client.SendAsync("Page.setDownloadBehavior", new
                    {
                        behavior = "allow",
                        downloadPath = "c:\\test"
                    });

                    await page.GoToAsync("https://google.com");

                    IElementHandle elh = await page.WaitForXPathAsync("//button/div[contains(text(),'alle')]");
                    await elh.ClickAsync();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string message = ex.Message;
        }
    }
}

If I switch to PuppeteerSharp version 17.0.0, and make the follwing modification as the code as is gives med the errors noted below.:
I still want to use XPATH as the selector, when running:
The last WaitForSelectorAsync does not work with XPATH. What is the right way to use XPATH?
public class Scraper
{
    public async Task Run()
    {
        ViewPortOptions vpo = new ViewPortOptions();
        vpo.Width = 1920;
        vpo.Height = 1280;

        BrowserFetcherOptions bfo = new BrowserFetcherOptions()
        {
            Path = System.IO.Path.GetTempPath()
        };

        //BrowserFetcher browserFetcher = new BrowserFetcher(bfo);
        await new BrowserFetcher(bfo).DownloadAsync();

        //await browserFetcher.DownloadAsync(BrowserFetcher.DefaultChromiumRevision);

        var lo = new LaunchOptions()
        {
            Headless = false,
            DefaultViewport = vpo,
            //ExecutablePath = browserFetcher.RevisionInfo(BrowserFetcher.DefaultChromiumRevision.ToString()).ExecutablePath
        };

        try
        {
            using (IBrowser browser = await Puppeteer.LaunchAsync(lo))
            {
                using (IPage page = await browser.NewPageAsync())
                {
                    await page.Client.SendAsync("Page.setDownloadBehavior", new
                    {
                        behavior = "allow",
                        downloadPath = "c:\\test"
                    });

                    await page.GoToAsync("https://google.com");

                    //IElementHandle elh = await page.WaitForXPathAsync("//button/div[contains(text(),'alle')]");
                    IElementHandle elh = await page.WaitForSelectorAsync("//button/div[contains(text(),'alle')]");
                    await elh.ClickAsync();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string message = ex.Message;
        }
    }
}

await browserFetcher.DownloadAsync(BrowserFetcher.DefaultChromiumRevision);

==> BrowserFetcher' does not contain a definition for 'DefaultChromiumRevision'
ExecutablePath = browserFetcher.RevisionInfo(BrowserFetcher.DefaultChromiumRevision.ToString()).ExecutablePath

==> 'BrowserFetcher' does not contain a definition for 'RevisionInfo' and no accessible extension method 'RevisionInfo' accepting a first argument of type 'BrowserFetcher' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
==> 'BrowserFetcher' does not contain a definition for 'DefaultChromiumRevision'
IElementHandle elh = await page.WaitForXPathAsync("//button/div[contains(text(),'alle')]");

==> 'IPage.WaitForXPathAsync(string, WaitForSelectorOptions)' is Obsolete. 'Use WaitForSelectorOptions instead'
using (IBrowser browser = await Puppeteer.LaunchAsync(lo))

==> 'An error occurred trying to start process 'C:\Work\Tools\Test\Test_PupetteerSharp\Test_PupetteerSharp\bin\Debug\net8.0\Chrome\Win64-124.0.6367.60\chrome-win64\chrome.exe' with working directory 'C:\Work\Tools\Test\Test_PupetteerSharp\Test_PupetteerSharp\bin\Debug\net8.0'. The system cannot find the file specified.'
IElementHandle elh = await page.WaitForSelectorAsync("//button/div[contains(text(),'alle')]");

==> Waiting for selector //button/div[contains(text(),'alle')] failed: Evaluation failed: DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': '//button/div[contains(text(),'alle')]' is not a valid selector.

Do you have an example of an HTML and an XPath to test?

I will Find and post some examples

I posted some examples, anybody can help me make the version 17/18 work?

I made some changes in your code and it worked for me.
First keep a reference to the downloaded browser:
var download = await new BrowserFetcher(bfo).DownloadAsync();

download has the GetExecutablePath function that will give you the executable path:
var lo = new LaunchOptions()
{
    Headless = true,
    DefaultViewport = vpo,
    ExecutablePath = download.GetExecutablePath(),
};

The last change is using the xpath/ engine in the WaitForSelectorAsync function:
IElementHandle elh = await page.WaitForSelectorAsync("xpath///button/div[contains(text(),'alle')]");

Notice that we have three / there, one for the engine selector and the other two for the XPath.
